# How I can define the location of the deployed app in AwsCodeploy based upon environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, continuous-deployment

Due to cost I am using a EC-2 where both production and staging reside upon seperate vhosts:

1. For Staging I use the following files:

   - Nginx Vhost: /etc/nginx/sites-available/staging.conf
   - WWW Root:  /var/www/staging
2. For Production I use the following files:

   - Nginx Vhost: /etc/nginx/sites-available/production.conf
   - WWW Root:  /var/www/production

For my deployment I use a single codeploy app but a seperate deployment group for each environment. And my appspec.yml is:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/staging

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: deploy/application-stop.sh
      runas: root
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: deploy/clean-files.sh
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: deploy/install_app.sh
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deploy/application-start.sh
      runas: root
```

How I can specify the nessesary deployment path based upon the deployment group. Is there a way to have parameterized deployment so I can set the nessesary paths where app will be deployed upon?

Answer (score 0):

An approach I followed is the follwing:

Upon build step I defined a plaintext environmental variable named `ENVIRONMENT` then yupon my build step I did the following (I use aws codebuild):

```
cp appspec.$ENVIRONMENT.yml appspec.yml
```

And I placed 2 appspec files:

1. For production named `appspec.production.yml`
2. For staging named `appspec.staging.yml`

And upon `ENVIRONMENT` variable I place the appropriate value:

1. `production` for production
2. `staging` for staging

Then upon my deployed artifacts in my buildspec I placed:

```
# rest ob buildspec.

artifacts:
  files:
   # rest of files here
   - appspec.yml
```

Furthermore In my case each appspec retrieves the nessesary webhook scripts from the following folders:

- `deploy/production` for production
- `deploy/staging` for staging

Then upon scripts and the seperate appspec files I place the correct paths for vhost and where app will be deployed upon. I same do upon each script in `deploy` folder.

For a new environment (named `development`) I can:

1. copy-paste the deploy/production into deploy/development
2. modify the scripts a bit
3. make the nessesary vhosts and folders upon the server
4. Make a new build step having `ENVIRONMENT` into `development`

To sum up the idea is to use multiple appspec files with a naming convention and copy the correct one into ethe epxected `appspec.yml` file. Then upon each appspec and webhook script I place the correct paths for vhost and application.

---

## Note:

For the build scripts, I think I could have each script load a config file or `source` a config script that uses the existing [environmental variables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/) in order to load the appropriate values. But I have not tested yet.